# Level sets of a BV function and its derivative

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Given $u \in BV(\Omega; \mathbb{R}^M)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, what is the relationship between its level sets and its distributional derivative $Db$?

More specifically, does Alberti rank-one theorem give any information on the structure of level sets of BV functions?